# Decreasing Multiple If Functions to One

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do the following with the macro below. If the searched value ['ASUS', 'LENOVO', 'DELL'] is one of them, it will write ['Computer']. If the wanted value ['U.S.A', 'United Kingdom', 'Russia'] is one of them, it will write ['Country']. I don't want to have two if functions. I want a single if function. How can I do that? Thank you from now.

```
function abc()
{
  var comp = [['ASUS' , 'LENOVO', 'DELL'] ,     ['Computer']];
  var cont = [['U.S.A' , 'United Kingdom', 'Russia'] ,     ['Country']];
  
  var findvalue = 'Russia';
  
  for(var n in comp[0][0] || cont[0][0]){
    if(comp[0][0][n] || cont[0][0][n] == findvalue) 
    {
      
      break
    }
    
  }
  
  if(comp[0].indexOf(findvalue) >=0)
  {
    Browser.msgBox(comp[1])
  }
  if(cont[0].indexOf(findvalue) >=0)
  {
    Browser.msgBox(cont[1])
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as they are in different variables like `comp`, `cont`, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would approach this in GAS:

```
  var comp = [['ASUS' , 'LENOVO', 'DELL'] ,     ['Computer']];
  var cont = [['U.S.A' , 'United Kingdom', 'Russia'] ,     ['Country']];
  var city = [['City1' , 'City2', 'City3'] ,     ['City']];      

  var findvalue = 'Russia';
  
  arr=[comp[0].indexOf(findvalue),cont[0].indexOf(findvalue),city[0].indexOf(findvalue)];
  
  if (arr[0] >=0){
         Logger.log(comp[1][0])
         }
  else if (arr[1] >=0){
  Logger.log(cont[1][0])
  }
  else if (arr[2] >=0){
  Logger.log(city[1][0])
  } 
  else {Logger.log("The item can not be found")}
```

Comment: @Aerial Code edits are  explicitly discouraged unless it's a typo. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/

Comment: Sorry I approved the changes by mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your support. But I will use more than 2. Like "Computer, Country, Company, Good, City, Plane, Car".

Comment: @Marios If you're ok with the changes, you can approve. If approved by mistake, You can rollback to previous versions.

Comment: @Halit you can add more items in the arr object. Then you can create else if blocks in the if statement to factor in all different options.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter, cleaner answer:

```
var categories = [comp, cont, city];

for (var i in categories) {
    if (categories[i][0].indexOf(findvalue) > -1) {
        return categories[i][1];
    }
}
return 'not found';
```

Much easier to update if you add categories later.